# How can a User create dates in my Calender (java)?

Tags: java, calendar

I m currently trying to code a Calender with java. 
I created 3 classes:

**1. Date**( includes year, month....)

**2. Event**(includes people, place, the class Date ... + an option to create dates )

**3. Mainclass** My mainclass that contains the menu.

My problem is that I don't know how the user is able to create his own date, because I have to create the object Termin myself... So, can somebody help me fix this? Thx in advance!

```
public class Event {
   private String mDescription, mPlace, mNames;
   private Date mStart, mEnd;

Termin(String description, String place, String names, Date start, Date end) {
    mBetreff = description;
    mOrt = place;
    mNamen = names;
    mBeginn = start;
    mEnde = end;
}

public void create() {
    Scanner read = new Scanner(System.in);
    System.out.println("Enter 1. description 2. place 3. names 4. start 5. end ein");
    mDescription = read.nextLine();
    mPlace = read.nextLine();
    mNames = read.nextLine();
}

public String toString() {
    return "Description : " + mDescription + "\nPlace: " + mPlace + "\nNames: " + mNames + "\nIts starts at " + mStart
            + " and ends at " + mEnd;
 }
}

public class Date {
   private int year, day, month, hours, minutes;

Datum(int year, int month, int day, int hours, int minutes) {
    this.day= day;
    this.year= year;
    this.month= month;
    this.hours= hours;
    this.minutes= minutes;
}

public String toString() {
    return "\n" + day + "." + month + "." + year + " um " + hours+ ":" + minutes;
}

public void enterDate() {
}
}
```

**EDIT:**

I asked this question 2 years ago, back when I just started coding and had no idea of oop and encapsulation ...

To answer my own question, for every newbie that also tries to create a terminal calender:

*Date* needs the following methos:

```
public setDate() {
   this.year = read.nextLine();
   ...
}
```

for every member.

*Event* takes the resulting object Date, either in the constructor or in a setter like method.

Comment: Please translate the critical portions of your code, such as those argument names. Stack Overflow is English-based.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Creating an instance-method to create an appointment is kind of... strange since one needs to create an appointment (called `Termin` in your case) to create an appointment. One possibility would be the [builder pattern](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Builder_pattern#Java). By having a public static inner builder class, you can set the constructor(s) private and enforce the use of that builder:

```
 public class Main {

    private int value;

    private Main(int value) {
        this.value = value;
    }

    public int getValue() {
        return (this.value);
    }

    public static class MainBuilder {

        boolean valueWasSet;
        int value;

        public MainBuilder() {
            this.valueWasSet = false;
            this.value = -1;
        }

        public void setValue(int value) {
            this.value = value;
            this.valueWasSet = true;
        }

        public Main build() {
            if (!this.valueWasSet) {
                throw new IllegalStateException("value must be set before a Main can be build.");
            }

            return (new Main(this.value));
        }
    }
}
```

(this is a simplified sketch to show the core mechanism on how to assert that certain values are set before constructing a `Main` through `MainBuilder`.

The process of constructing a `Main` would be:

```
MainBuilder builder = new MainBuilder();

builder.setValue(100);
// all following Main's will have a value of 100
Main mainOne = builder.build();
Main mainTwo = builder.build();

builder.setValue(200);
// all following Main's will have a value of 200
Main mainThree = builder.build();
Main mainFour = builder.build();
```

Comment: Thank you! I appreciate your help